# Changes in a model not saving. Rails 4.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-migrations

I've just created a user model using scaffolding, as follows:

```
rails g scaffold user name:string
```

I run db:migrate and everything works fine, but when I try to add a new field, it is not saving it in the database.
I add the field by doing:

```
rails g migration add_surname_to_users surname:string
```

No weird messages when I run rake db:migrate, the database table is ok, the form has been edited to alow surname input, as it have the show and index views to display it properly.
However, it is not saving the form value given into the database.

Any clues about how to fix it? It's quite annoying not being able to alter my models.

Comment: Could you share that migration file? If you're on Rails4, make sure you have this new attribute into `user_params` in your controller (because of `strong_parameters`).

Comment: Open rails console and try to instantiate u=User.new(name: "fdf", surnam: "Fdf") and save the data, check for errors using u.errors.full_messages

Comment: Markets you're are my hero!!
Right to the point, it was because of the **strong parameters**.
I've googling it for a couple of hours and I could'nt find anything.
Thanks a million!

Comment: No prob man. I'm going to add a real answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using `Rails4` (I think so), make sure you have this new attribute into `user_params` in your controller (because of `strong_parameters`):

```
def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:name, :surname)
end
```

It's a typical mistake when new to this `Rails` version.

Further information here: [strong_parameters](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters)