# Rails - added new attribute to model, value not saving

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've had the same symptoms as this issue:

[Changes in a model not saving. Rails 4.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23140679/changes-in-a-model-not-saving-rails-4-1/23141132#23141132)

The only suggestion there (and accepted answer as it solved that problem), regarding strong parameters and not permitting the new attribute in the params, was the first mistake I had made.  I fixed that by adding it to the params.  I then noticed that the column name I'd added was "type", which apparently is a reserved word.  So I fixed that too, by renaming it to "assessmenttype", but it's still not saving the value. I know the value exists in the @assessment object that is passed to the "new" page, because I can print out `@assessment.assessmenttype` from there, and it matches.  However, somehow this is not being pushed to the database when "create" does its `@assessment.save` action.

assessments_controller.rb:

```
def new
    ...
    @assessment = current_user.assessments.build
    @assessment.name = params[:name]
    @assessment.assessmenttype = params[:assessmenttype]
    respond_with(@assessment)
end

def create
    @assessment = current_user.assessments.build(assessment_params)
    @assessment.save
    ...
end
...
def assessment_params
    params.require(:assessment).permit(:name, :assessmenttype)
end
```

Does anyone have any other suggestions, apart from the accepted answer in that question, as to why this might be happening?  I'm clearly missing something obvious that staring at it for a couple of hours is not letting me see!

Assessments table schema:

```
CREATE TABLE "assessments" (
    "id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, 
    "name" varchar(255), 
    "created_at" datetime, 
    "updated_at" datetime, 
    "user_id" integer, 
    "assessmenttype" varchar(255)
);
```

Example of a link which is being used to call the "new" method:

```
<%= link_to 'Assess me', new_assessment_path(:name => qt.name, 
    :tid =>qt.id, :assessmenttype => "qt"), 
    class: "btn" %>
```

Example calling Assessment.new and saving the record from the console:

```
irb(main):006:0> a=Assessment.new(name:"one", user_id:1, assessmenttype:"qt")
=> #<Assessment id: nil, name: "one", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, user_id: 1, assessmenttype: "qt">
irb(main):007:0> a.save
(0.0ms)  begin transaction
D, [2015-12-11T16:07:51.875496 #2296] DEBUG -- :    (0.0ms)  begin transaction
SQL (1.0ms)  INSERT INTO "assessments" ("assessmenttype", "created_at", "name", "updated_at", "user_id") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
[["assessmenttype", "qt"], ["created_at", "2015-12-11 16:07:51.877496"], ["name", "one"], ["updated_at", "2015-12-11 16:07:51.877496"], ["user_id", 1]]
D, [2015-12-11T16:07:51.882582 #2296] DEBUG -- :   SQL (1.0ms)  INSERT INTO "assessments" ("assessmenttype", "created_at", "name", "updated_at", "user_id") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["assessmenttype", "qt"], ["created_at", "2015-12-11 16:07:51.877496"], ["name", "one"], ["updated_at", "2015-12-11 16:07:51.877496"], ["user_id", 1]]
(4.0ms)  commit transaction
D, [2015-12-11T16:07:51.894498 #2296] DEBUG -- :    (4.0ms)  commit transaction
=> true
irb(main):008:0>
```

Comment: can u post exact error you getting and assemments table schema to look?

Comment: Check development.log to see exactly what parameters are passed to the `create` action. Also, make sure in the assessment form you use `assessmenttype` and not `type`

Comment: @Padmanaban - there's no error.  I'll add the table schema.

Comment: @eugen - there's nothing in the development.log unfortunately.  If there were I'm sure it'd be helpful!

Comment: have you tried in console? Or add byebug to see what exactly happening in the create action.

Comment: Can you add the code that is calling the `new` method, specifically the part related to type or assessment type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you certain you've included a hidden field in the view form, that is that param?

`<%= f.hidden_field :assessmenttype %>`

If you don't have that field available in the view, then the params as passed back when posted won't include it, even if you used it to build the object in the first place. HTTP is a stateless protocol, we create new objects every time.

Comment: Bingo.  Thanks so much, it was bound to be something this obvious!

Comment: No worries! Glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

In the new method you are using `@assessment.assessmenttype = params[:type]`

However, the `assessment_params` do not allow `type`, instead `:assessmenttype`

Change the new method to the following:

```
def new
    ...
    @assessment = current_user.assessments.build
    @assessment.name = params[:name]
    @assessment.assessmenttype = params[:assessmenttype]
    respond_with(@assessment)
end
```

**Update**

You said in the comments that its the param passed in (and provided a url string). The url string should read....

```
http://localhost:3000/assessments/new?name=Assessment+name&tid=1&assessmenttype=qt
```

not....

```
http://localhost:3000/assessments/new?name=Assessment+name&tid=1&type=qt
```

....as this is the name of the param you have allowed in `assessment_params`.

You have two options:

1 - If you want to keep the existing parameter string you can add `:type` to the list of allowed params. This part alone should allow your code to work.

2 - Change the name of the parameter coming in. If it's from a form, the form input should be linked to 'assessmenttype'. If its in code it should be `params[:assessmenttype] = 'qt'`

Comment: Even if this is not exactly your issue, it's going to be related to that param name somewhere in your code (I think).

Comment: That param is the parameter that is passed into the new action - e.g. http://localhost:3000/assessments/new?name=Assessment+name&tid=1&type=qt

It's being mapped to the assessment.assessmenttype attribute before I try to save the assessment object, so this shouldn't matter?

Comment: @MartinGreenaway I'd urge you to use the same param name everywhere. The fact that `:type` is not is your list of allowed params probably means it's not reaching the new method, so rails will not save anything. Try adding :type into the list of allowed params. I do still think its a naming conflict.

Comment: Also, whats the value of `params[:type]` when you log it to console? And are you calling the `new` method following a form submission?

Comment: I have changed <code>params[:type]</code> to <code>params[:assessmenttype]</code> and amended the links that fire off the request to the new form, and it hasn't made any difference.

Comment: It's a self assessment tool where the user can assess on a number of topics, categorised in a certain way. The reason for adding in the "type" (or "assessmenttype" as it now is) is to enable some reporting, which wasn't in the initial plan, on how users are using the assessments.  The "new" view presents the form, and at that point the "assessmenttype" value is known. It seems to be when going back to the controller to "create" that the value is lost.

Comment: @MartinGreenaway Can you add the new url string after making those changes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97661/discussion-between-martin-greenaway-and-tonyedwardspz).

Comment: For what it's worth, thank you very much for your efforts in trying to resolve this.

Comment: No problem. Glad you got an answer. We both learned something from this question :-)